# Register all services in a specific assembly and namespace using Windsor?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

This is probably a bit trivial, but I must be doing something wrong. I have an MVC project, where I have two projects controlled by IoC using Windsor:

1. The MVC project
2. A project with services

Normally I would register the services using an XML file. However, I want to register all services and interfaces automatically.

All my services is placed in my services project called `LetterAmazer.Business.Services`, under the namespace `LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services`. My interfaces, which the services derive from, is in the namespace `LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Domain` .

I have tried to set it up in my `Global.asax`, in the following way:

```
private void InitializeContainer()
        {
            var oldProvider = FilterProviders.Providers.Single(f => f is FilterAttributeFilterProvider);
            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(oldProvider);

            Container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(this.Container));
            Container.Install(new BootstrapInstaller());

            Container.Register(
                Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("LetterAmazer.Business.Services"))
                    .InNamespace("LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services"));
            Container.Install(new WebWindsorInstaller());

            var provider = new WindsorFilterAttributeFilterProvider(this.Container);
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);

            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WindsorDependencyResolver(ServiceFactory.Container));
        }

        public IWindsorContainer Container
        {
            get { return ServiceFactory.Container; }
        }
```

But this provides several issues. First of all, it doesn't find any services when running the `Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory` call. Furthermore, this wouldn't get the interfaces.

So I am basically asking how to solve this problem in a best practice way? I have 30+ services, and I want them all, so it would make sense to add them by conventation rather than hand pick.

**EDIT:**

The code I ended up with:

```
  var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Server.MapPath("~/bin/LetterAmazer.Business.Services.dll")); ;
        Container.Register(
            Classes.FromAssembly(assembly)
            .InNamespace("LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services")
            .WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used `Classes.FromAssemblyInDirectory()` method but I usually use `FromThisAssembly()` or 'FromAssemblyContaining()' methods to select assemblies. Simetimes `FromAssembly("AssemblyName")` is used.

I would write the following code the following way if there is no base interface for all seervices:

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssembly("LetterAmazer.Business.Services")
        .InNamespace("LetterAmazer.Business.Services.Services")
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

If there is a generic interface `IService<T>` I would use the following registration:

```
container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssembly("LetterAmazer.Business.Services")
        .BasedOn(typeof(IService<>))
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

I'd like to add that all your services will be registered as Singletons if life style is not specified during registration.

You can find detailed information in the article **[Registering components by conventions](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx)** from Castle Windsor website.

Comment: You sir, are just amazing! Thanks a lot